# How to generate a hashmap for huge chunk of data?

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashtable

I want to make a map such that a set of pointers point to arrays of dynamic size.
I did use hashing with chaining. But since data I am using it for is huge, the program give `std::bad_alloc` after few iterations. The reason of which may be `new` used to generate the linked list.

Someone please suggest which data structure shall I use? 
Or anything else that can improve memory usage with my hash table?

Program is in C++.

This is what my code looks like:
Initialization of hashtable:

```
class Link
{ 
  public:
         double iData; 
         Link* pNext; 
         Link(double it) : iData(it) 
         { }
         void displayLink()
         { cout << iData << " "; }
}; 

class List
 {
  private:
          Link* pFirst; 
  public:
         List() 
         { pFirst = NULL; }
         void insert(double key) 
         {

           if(pFirst==NULL)
           pFirst = new Link(key);
       else
          {
        Link* pLink = new Link(key);
        pLink->pNext = pFirst;
        pFirst = pLink;
       }

         }     

 }; 
class HashTable
{      
  public:
         int arraySize;
         vector<List*> hashArray; 

         HashTable(int size) 
         {

            hashArray.resize(size); 
            for(int j=0; j<size; j++) 
            hashArray[j] = new List; 
         }
};
```

main snippet:

```
int t_sample = 1000;
 for(int i=0; i < k; i++)                                // initialize random position
{
        x[i] = (cal_rand() * dom_sizex);   //dom_sizex = 20e-10  cal_rand() generates rand no between 0 and 1
        y[i] = (cal_rand() * dom_sizey);    //dom_sizey = 10e-10
}

for(int t=0; t < t_sample; t++)
{
 int size;
 size = cell_nox * cell_noy; //size of hash table cell_nox = 212, cell_noy = 424

 HashTable theHashTable(size); //make table
 int hashValue = 0;

 for(int n=0; n<k; n++)   // k = 10*212*424
 {
  int m = x[n] /cell_width;     //cell_width = 4.7e-8
  int l = y[n] / cell_width;

   hashValue = (kx*l)+m;
   theHashTable.hashArray[hashValue]->insert(n); 

  }

   -------
   -------
 }
```

Comment: Roughly how much data are we talking about here?

Comment: @T.C. 89888 keys. approx 10 values in each. iterated 1000 times.

Comment: So you need to store ~900 million values in total in memory? Even if it's only 4 bytes per value you'd run out of the available virtual address space for a 32-bit program. No data structure change can fix that.

Comment: @T.C. but people do run such simulations in Fortran. Isn't there any option to handle this?

Comment: @aks: Sure there is, a 64bit OS and enough RAM hardware.

Comment: @aks: well - you might comment on whether you need to keep all the values from each iteration simultaneously, or whether there's some way of processing and discarding some of those results earlier?  Depending on your data access needs, you might consider configuring a good whack of swap space, or explicitly writing the values to disk until they're needed agin.  Also, can you compile a 64-bit app?  How much RAM do you have available?

Comment: @TonyD i just have to update these values in every iteration. No need to keep the values separately from each iteration. System has 4GB RAM. 64 bit

Comment: @aks So you really have only ~900k values and are only updating them in each iteration rather than making new ones? Then you probably need to look for memory leaks in your code.

Comment: As T.C. says, if it makes it through a few iterations then crashes, that suggests it had enough memory for the initial iteration but leaked afterwards.  More generally, an `std::unordered_map<key, std::vector<value>>` sounds about right, unless you have e.g. contiguous incrementing keys - then you can just have `vector<value>`.  If there's very little variation between min and max length you may want to consider a `std::array<>` with an initial length element or trailing sentinel.

Comment: @T.C. I have updated my code snippet in the question. Plz check it if you could find something.

Comment: @TonyD I have updated my code snippet in the question. Plz check it, if you could find something.

Comment: @aks: I  don't see a reason to individually `new` all those `List` objects in the `hashArray`. Just use `vector<List> hashArray;`, it will be more compact and faster than all those `new` calls. Your code also doesn't show any use of `delete` so you're probably leaking memory all over the place.

Comment: @aks: why are you writing your own containers?  It's horribly inefficient to use a linked list when there will be ~10 small elements - all those pointers + every heap allocation has housekeeping overheads and possible rounding-up to a larger block size that are significant here.  A (contiguous) `vector<double>` is a much better idea (i.e. for the whole thing `std::unordered_map<std::vector<double>>`.  You don't have any code to `delete` dynamic memory after each iteration....

Comment: There's still not enough source code to deduce the errors, but there's some clear concerns: instead of using `hashArray[hashValue]` I recommend using `hashArray.at(hashValue)` - then it will throw an exception if `hashValue >= size`.  You can put a `try/catch` block around your code and print any exceptions.  Separately, I suggest you use an interactive debugger or add some `std::cerr << ...` trace statements to tell you what's being assigned to what... then you can start debugging your code in a systematic fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, use a Standard Container. In your specific case, you might want:

- either `std::unordered_multimap<int, double>`
- or `std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<double>>`

(Note: if you do not have C++11, those are available in Boost)

Your main loop becomes (using the second option):

```
typedef std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<double>> HashTable;

for(int t = 0; t < t_sample; ++t)
{
    size_t const size = cell_nox * cell_noy;
       // size of hash table cell_nox = 212, cell_noy = 424

    HashTable theHashTable;
    theHashTable.reserve(size);

    for (int n = 0; n < k; ++n)   // k = 10*212*424
    {
        int m = x[n] / cell_width;     //cell_width = 4.7e-8
        int l = y[n] / cell_width;

        int const cellId = (kx*l)+m;

        theHashTable[cellId].push_back(n);
    }
}
```

This will not leak memory (reliably), although of course you might have other leaks, and thus will give you a reliable baseline. It is also probably faster than your approach, with a more convenient interface, etc...

In general you should not re-invent the wheel, unless you have a specific need that is not addressed by the available wheels or you are actually trying to learn how to create a wheel or to create a better wheel.

Answer (score 0):

The OS has to solve the same issues with the memory pages, maybe it's worth looking at how that is done? First of all, let's assume all pages are on the disk. A page is a fixed size memory chunk. For your use case, let's say it's an array of your records. Because RAM is limited, the OS maintains a mapping between the page number and it's location in RAM.

So, let's say your pages have 1000 records, and you want to access record 2024, you would ask the OS for page 2, and read record 24 from that page. That way, your map is only 1/1000 in size.

Now, if your page has no mapping to a memory location, then it is either on disk or has never been accessed before (is empty). Then you need to swap out another page, and load that page from disk (and update the location mapping).

This is a very simplified description of what happens and i wouldn't be surprised if someone jumps me in the neck for describing it like this.

The point is:

What does this mean for you?

First of all, your data exceeds your RAM - you won't get around writing to disk, if you don't want to try compression first.
Second, your chains can work as pages if you want, but i wonder whether just paging your hashcode would work better. What i mean is, use the upper bits as page number, and the lower bits as offset in the page. Avoiding collisions is still key, as you want to load the least pages possible. You can still chain your pages, and end up with a much smaller map.
Second - a crucial part is deciding which pages to swap out to make room for the new pages. LRU should do ok. If you can better predict which pages you will (not) need, so much better for you.
Third - you need placeholders for your pages to tell you whether they are in-memory or on disk.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am sorry but most of this bounced off my head. Let me rephrase my question. Just know what I am actually trying to do with my code. I have 898880 particles, 89888 cells. So 10 particles in each cell. Now since i am randomly allocating position to these particles i need to index each particle to its cell. So i did map 10 values to a cell using linked list. And the cells are marked by hashvalues of the hashtable. When I simulated this system with more than 200 iterations, the program terminated with this: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'

Comment: So, what are these cells, spatial positions/volumes? Why use hash tables at all, is a plain array not enough? From what i understood from your code, your iterations are independet of each other? Can't you just save the results of each iteration to disk before you start the next one, and discard it from memory?

Comment: do you mean i shall initialize 89888 arrays? i have used this to delete:   
      for(int m=0; m<kx; m++) 
      {
      for(int l=0; l<ky; l++)
      {    hashValue = (kx*l)+m;       
         delete[] theHashTable.hashArray[hashValue]; 
        
  }
    } void del_list()
             {
     Link* pCurrent = pFirst;           
                 while (pCurrent != NULL)
                 {      
                 Link* del = pCurrent;        
                 pCurrent = pCurrent->pNext;     
                 free (del);            
          }
          pFirst = NULL;
    }

Comment: Also, are there always 10 particles in a cell or is that just the expected value? The deleting looks ok for me, but i have more experience with Java, to be honest.

Comment: no 10 is average. it will change from cell to cell.